# DocuSign - External site API integration - Email PDF with Signature request and have pdf returned to external site

Tags: docusignapi

I want to know if the following is possible (or if there is a recommended alternative design).

Through an external application (initiate via C# workflow), what we are hoping for is the ability to email a DocuSign request to sign a custom generated PDF document and upon signing, have that signed document returned to our application where it can be stored in our attachments repository. Is this specific scenario possible with having that document returned to an external source? or is there a recommended alternative option that may be a good compromise?  The only other possibility I can think of if the above is not possible, is to send a custom email with a link back to our application where we could embed the pdf for signing via docusign api and capture the completed PDF for storing.

thoughts?

We haven't tried anything yet, we are just exploring what is possible so that we may properly inform our client and they can decide to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do all of this with DocuSign.
Currently the way you handle this is using remote signing, where DocuSign will email the envelope (Which is what DocuSign calls a transaction with documents and signatures) to the recipients. When it's complete - you get an event via a [webhook](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/) that enables you to download the completed (signed) document from the DocuSign cloud. Then you can archive it yourself to your system using whatever 3rd party API or method you use to do that.

I would suggest that you try to create a developer account and download a [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart) with some sample code that you can learn about to see it in action.
Also, if you are interested in learning about new upcoming technologies that may improve your experience - feel free to email me directly.

Comment: Thank you for this information and resources, this is exactly what I was looking for.

I will explore further, but this is what we needed to continue our process.